# How to create custom shapes in css

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm wondering how I can create something as follows:

[image: Custom CSS shape]

The grey containers are no issue, but the pink menu container is driving me crazy. How do you create something like this? Should I use a picture for this and align the div on top (Which seems way to fragile) or should I create a custom CSS-shape and if yes, how?

Comment: There is literally something called css-shape. Have you tried googling it?

Comment: Use css3 [Skew Transformations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/skew).

Comment: I think that pink container is an image or maybe a custom navbar. Why don't you inspect the element using your browser to get more insights.

Comment: I have googled it and yes I know about transform-skew, but it seems way too fragile because you will have 2 divs that need to be "connected" and changing screens and resolutions or zooming will look horrible. And this a picture not an actual website.

Comment: @JobdeNooijer start something, write a little code, whatever you understand, then rest of the developers may help you. Nobody would like to start the whole things from scratch and give their much of time into it.

Comment: SVG and/or canvas would be another possibility

Comment: check this link out, https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/.

Answer (score 0):

Make a simple nav-bar with a pink background. Then below the logo button add a random element i-e `<p class="extension"></p>` give it padding and some width.

```
.extension {
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
    width: 260px;
    background-color: pink;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

whatever block you want to use,use css skew.refer link-https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transform_skew